Wrong result in VRP by or-tools with locations only visitable by certain vehicles
I’m working on a rather simple version of the VRP. To the example provided on the OR-Tools website, I’ve added just one constraint. Specifically, there are 3 vehicles: A, B, and C, and 16 locations. All vehicles start and return to the depot, which is considered as location 0. The only constraint I introduced using the routing.SetAllowedVehiclesForIndex command is that vehicle A can visit all locations, vehicle B can visit locations 1, 2,..., 8, and vehicle C can visit locations 9, 10,..., 16.
For the local search algorithm, I used global local search, while for the first solution algorithm, I tried all the ones available.
The problem is that when I get a result, regardless of the type of algorithm used for the first solution search, vehicle A is not assigned to any locations. Is it possible to solve this issue? If so, how?
Here is the code below:
from ortools.constraint_solver import routing_enums_pb2
from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp
    
specific_locations = [
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
    [9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
]
    
    
def create_data_model():
        """Stores the data for the problem."""
        data = {}
        data["distance_matrix"] = [
            # fmt: off
          [0, 548, 776, 696, 582, 274, 502, 194, 308, 194, 536, 502, 388, 354, 468, 776, 662],
          [548, 0, 684, 308, 194, 502, 730, 354, 696, 742, 1084, 594, 480, 674, 1016, 868, 1210],
          [776, 684, 0, 992, 878, 502, 274, 810, 468, 742, 400, 1278, 1164, 1130, 788, 1552, 754],
          [696, 308, 992, 0, 114, 650, 878, 502, 844, 890, 1232, 514, 628, 822, 1164, 560, 1358],
          [582, 194, 878, 114, 0, 536, 764, 388, 730, 776, 1118, 400, 514, 708, 1050, 674, 1244],
          [274, 502, 502, 650, 536, 0, 228, 308, 194, 240, 582, 776, 662, 628, 514, 1050, 708],
          [502, 730, 274, 878, 764, 228, 0, 536, 194, 468, 354, 1004, 890, 856, 514, 1278, 480],
          [194, 354, 810, 502, 388, 308, 536, 0, 342, 388, 730, 468, 354, 320, 662, 742, 856],
          [308, 696, 468, 844, 730, 194, 194, 342, 0, 274, 388, 810, 696, 662, 320, 1084, 514],
          [194, 742, 742, 890, 776, 240, 468, 388, 274, 0, 342, 536, 422, 388, 274, 810, 468],
          [536, 1084, 400, 1232, 1118, 582, 354, 730, 388, 342, 0, 878, 764, 730, 388, 1152, 354],
          [502, 594, 1278, 514, 400, 776, 1004, 468, 810, 536, 878, 0, 114, 308, 650, 274, 844],
          [388, 480, 1164, 628, 514, 662, 890, 354, 696, 422, 764, 114, 0, 194, 536, 388, 730],
          [354, 674, 1130, 822, 708, 628, 856, 320, 662, 388, 730, 308, 194, 0, 342, 422, 536],
          [468, 1016, 788, 1164, 1050, 514, 514, 662, 320, 274, 388, 650, 536, 342, 0, 764, 194],
          [776, 868, 1552, 560, 674, 1050, 1278, 742, 1084, 810, 1152, 274, 388, 422, 764, 0, 798],
          [662, 1210, 754, 1358, 1244, 708, 480, 856, 514, 468, 354, 844, 730, 536, 194, 798, 0],
            # fmt: on
        ]
        data["num_vehicles"] = 3
        data["depot"] = 0
        return data
    
    
def print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution):
        """Prints solution on console."""
        print(f"Objective: {solution.ObjectiveValue()}")
        max_route_distance = 0
        for vehicle_id in range(data["num_vehicles"]):
            index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
            plan_output = f"Route for vehicle {vehicle_id}:\n"
            route_distance = 0
            while not routing.IsEnd(index):
                plan_output += f" {manager.IndexToNode(index)} -> "
                previous_index = index
                index = solution.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
                route_distance += routing.GetArcCostForVehicle(
                    previous_index, index, vehicle_id
                )
            plan_output += f"{manager.IndexToNode(index)}\n"
            plan_output += f"Distance of the route: {route_distance}m\n"
            print(plan_output)
            max_route_distance = max(route_distance, max_route_distance)
        print(f"Maximum of the route distances: {max_route_distance}m")
    
    
    
def main():
        """Entry point of the program."""
        # Instantiate the data problem.
        data = create_data_model()
    
        # Create the routing index manager.
        manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(
            len(data["distance_matrix"]), data["num_vehicles"], data["depot"]
        )
    
        # Create Routing Model.
        routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)
    
        # Create and register a transit callback.
        def distance_callback(from_index, to_index):
            """Returns the distance between the two nodes."""
            # Convert from routing variable Index to distance matrix NodeIndex.
            from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
            to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
            return data["distance_matrix"][from_node][to_node]
    
        transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(distance_callback)
    
        # Define cost of each arc.
        routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)
    
        # Add Distance constraint.
        dimension_name = "Distance"
        routing.AddDimension(
            transit_callback_index,
            0,  # no slack
            3000,  # vehicle maximum travel distance
            True,  # start cumul to zero
            dimension_name,
        )
        distance_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(dimension_name)
        distance_dimension.SetGlobalSpanCostCoefficient(100)
    
        for i in range(data["num_vehicles"]):
            for j in range(len(specific_locations[i])):  
                routing.SetAllowedVehiclesForIndex([i], manager.NodeToIndex(specific_locations[i][j]))
    
        # Setting first solution heuristic.
        search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
        search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
            routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC
        )
        search_parameters.local_search_metaheuristic = (
            routing_enums_pb2.LocalSearchMetaheuristic.GUIDED_LOCAL_SEARCH
        )
    
        search_parameters.time_limit.seconds = 30
    
        # Solve the problem.
        solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)
    
        # Print solution on console.
        if solution:
            print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution)
        else:
            print("No solution found !")
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

The solution I get is:
Objective: 267648
Route for vehicle 0:
 0 -> 0
Distance of the route: 0m

Route for vehicle 1:
 0 ->  5 ->  8 ->  6 ->  2 ->  1 ->  4 ->  3 ->  7 -> 0
Distance of the route: 2624m

Route for vehicle 2:
 0 ->  9 ->  10 ->  16 ->  14 ->  13 ->  15 ->  11 ->  12 -> 0
Distance of the route: 2624m

Maximum of the route distances: 2624m
Press any key to continue . . .


each call to SetAllowedVehiclesForIndex on a given index overwrite the previous call on the same index.
You need to collect all vehicles for a given index.

That's perfect, thank you
